# How to get rid of the whitespace at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

Can someone please help me eliminate the extra whitespace at the bottom of this website?  http://www.vonlay.com/

This image shows what I am trying to remove: http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/8837/screenshot20110607at715.png

Here is how I have the footer setup.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body > #wrapper { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }
#footer { position: relative; height: 140px; z-index: 10; clear: both;
    margin-top: -140px; background: #700; color: #fff; }
```

Comment: Set margin & padding on html & body to 0? (My CSS is seriously rusty, hence a comment instead of an answer...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should add:

```
#footer .content p {
    margin-bottom: 0
}
```

---

I actually wrote another answer before that one that explains what's going on properly, with an alternative fix, here it is:

You should add `overflow: hidden` to `#footer`.

This will resolve the problem, which is that the `margin` on the `p` element inside `<div class="copyright-notice">` is collapsing through `#footer`. See: [collapsing margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).

If this seems unlikely to you, try adding this, *just to see what happens*:

```
#footer .content p {
    margin-bottom: 200px
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I went with the overflow: hidden solution.

Comment: By the way, that article explaining collapsing margins was very helpful.  Thanks for that reference!

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the height of your footer:

```
#footer { height: 145px; }
```

Comment: Well, it does work :) If you're interested to know where the gap is coming from, give my answer a read.

Comment: I am going with thirtydot's implementation, but this worked as well.  I swear I tried a lot of things last night including this, but I must have been missing something.  Thanks.

Comment: @thebitguru, his solution actually solves the underlying issue, mine is more of a patch. You're right to go with his :) Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Try setting padding and/or margin on the bottom to zero for the footer and/or body.

Answer (score 0):

Try using positioning:

```
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the footer class change

```
 height: 160px;
```

try....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add a wrapper around every HTML element in your "body" element, excluding the footer, then in CSS do this:

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: calc(100vh -<your-footer-height>px);
}
```

You don't have to add any styling to the footer since it's not in the wrapper. so the content just takes the viewport height of the device screen.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your section CSS

```
min-height: 100vh;
```