# Free Space in <div>

Tags: html, css

I Can't find error. It's like padding, but padding is 0. Please help me if you can. I kill about hour. You can check it http://codepen.io/sergeviper/pen/ONZWEN 
It should be two divs in one big div with fixed height and width should be 100%. 
["PICTURE"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rG8o.png)

```css
.card {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 1);
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.map {
  width: 725px;
  height: 368px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.auth {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 275px;
  height: 368px;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-size: 8pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="map">
    <img class="map" src="img/map.png" height="374px">
  </div>
  <div class="auth">
    <form>
      <h1>Вход на сайт</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Логин" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" />
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="ВОйти" />
    </form>
    <h2 style="color:#999999">Войти с помощью:</h2>
    <div class="social">
      <div id="vk"></div>
      <div id="ok"></div>
      <div id="fb"></div>
      <div id="gp"></div>
      <div id="tw"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="reg"><a href="">Регистрация</a>
    </div>
    <div class="subreg"><a href="">Забыли пароль</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a demonstration of the effect. Use something like jsfiddle.net to set it up. Thanks.

Comment: http://codepen.io/sergeviper/pen/ONZWEN

Comment: Well, you obviously have to add a padding to the "second" `<div>`, if that is what you mean: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNGpKR

Comment: it should be like one big div (class card) consist of two divs(map an auth)

Comment: arkascha, if you delete padding in auth you can see black line bottom. I need kill it:)

Comment: It is. See the silver border I also added in my version, It contains _both_, the map on the left hand side and the form on the right hand side. Not sure what you are asking now.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I only now understand what your question was. Wait a minute...

Comment: Sorry for my English and thank you)

Comment: You mix inline height and width attributes with css styling rules. That rarely is a good idea. It is either or and the clearly preferred way is to use css styling rules. If you remove some stuff, then also the line at the bottom vanishes: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNGpKR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the image is 'inline(-block)'. This causes the line-height to create space below the image. Change the image to 'display: block' and this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **margin-bottom: 0;**
If it doesn't work, read this - [How to get rid of the whitespace at the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273032/how-to-get-rid-of-the-whitespace-at-the-bottom), possible solution/duplicate.